# Unable to install glass sample using adb on MAC

Tags: android, eclipse, google-glass

I am trying to install Timer sample from GDK onto my glass. adb is configured correctly and picks up the device. However when i try to do install the sample app i get the following error

2671 KB/s (228119 bytes in 0.083s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/MenuActivity.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

My AndroidManifest.xml file looks like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.glass.sample.timer"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

I have updated the SDK to the latest version there is.

Also i dont see the device being picked up by Eclipse device chooser while launching the app. I am guessing it is related to the SDK issue. Any help on fixing this?

Comment: Is your Glass updated to XE16?

Comment: On device info it says XE12 up to date. Should I upgrade?

Comment: I suspected this and check on glass developers page and did not find any firmware update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XE12 is **API level 15**. XE16 is API level 19 (KitKat, check the [release notes](https://support.google.com/glass/answer/4578099?hl=en)).

You should either update your device (strange that it didn't do so automatically) or change your `<uses-sdk>` to 15.

Comment: Thank you. I will try updating to XE19. My glass does not connect to wifi at all. I have tried it all. It just wouldn't connect. I am guessing that is the reason it is not automatically updated to XE16

Comment: How do i update my glass to XE16? I tried factory reset, it doesnt seem to update it.

Comment: @G3M It should be automatic if connected to wifi, charging, and with 50% battery or more. Otherwise you can force it. See https://support.google.com/glass/answer/3226482?hl=en